# change Apache document root in XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, document-root

I have just downloaded a website which contains static html pages from a hosting to my localhost (XAMPP) and saved it to a subdirectory in XAMPP htdocs directory.

When I view the local website in browser, all css, js files and images were missing. I checked the HTML source code and saw that it's all using relative path for css/js or href link. For example:

```
<a href="/contact">Text Link</a>
```

It works on the hosting, but on my localhost, it points to http://localhost/contact instead of http://localhost/bf/contact (my subdirectory name is **bf**). This structure is applied to all css, js files too and they could not be loaded.

I have tried to add .htaccess file to my subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bf/
RewriteRule (.*) /bf/$1 [L]
```

But it still not works. I don't want to manually change all src, href, and link in every HTML pages to fix this. There would be a way to make Apache recognize the root is /bf instead of / , applied to all files in this directory only. Please help !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this work by setting apache virtual host at locally as describe below:

For example in ubuntu /etc/apache2/httpd.conf,
If you are using XAMPP on window that is the case, then the httpd.conf file should be C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf.

Please follow below steps to configure your local sites at local server:

```
------------
Step 1
------------
i.e 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.demo.tst ( Any name you want to set )
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bf"
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bf">
      AllowOverride All  
      Order allow,deny  
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
  #RackEnv development
  ErrorLog C:/xampp/htdocs/bf/logs/test.demo.tst_error
  CustomLog C:/xampp/htdocs/bf/logs/test.demo.tst_access common
</VirtualHost>

------------
Step 2
------------
Than you need to restart apache service

------------
Step 3
------------
Than you need to do setting in your hosts files
for example in hosts file place below entry 

127.0.0.1       test.demo.tst

------------
Step 4
------------
Than you can access this url test.demo.tst local server.

I hope this informations would be helpful to you.
```

Comment: Thanks Atul for your answer. It almost works. Except for the fact that when  I open another local site which is located in another subdirectory on my localhost, for example http://localhost/abc , then the object not found error encountered. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: @LocNguyen I think you should make configuration with other url and settings same way as I mentioned above for all such local sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bf/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bf/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hope this is helpful to you. And your apache rewrite mode must be on in php.ini